How to let messenger apps notifications from specific contacts bypass DND?
I have DND mode ON at night.
But I want the phone to ignore the DND and do play the sound for messages from specific contacts in messenger apps
Note: I'm not talking about phone calls - there is a setting for this - but about sound notifications for incoming messages in the messenger app (namely Telegram, but I might want to do the same in others later - Discord, WhatsApp)

There's no setting for what you want.
